# SqlKata - Is there any way to tell the SqlKata compiler to NOT wrap Identifiers when building the query string?

Tags: sqlkata

Is there any way to tell the SqlKata compiler to NOT wrap Identifiers when building the query string?  (Double quotes for PostgreSql and Square brackets for SqlServer)

For example, when building a query against a PostgreSql database I would like the compiler to create:  SELECT CDR.InstanceID FROM CallDetails as CDR

instead of:

SELECT "CDR"."InstanceID" FROM "CallDetails as "CDR"

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the desired compiler and change the default `OpeningIdentifier` and `ClosingIdentifier`.

```cs
public class MyCompiler: PostgresCompiler
{
    protected override string OpeningIdentifier { get; set; } = "";
    protected override string ClosingIdentifier { get; set; } = "";
}
```

and use it instead

Comment: Thank you.  I gave this a try and unfortunately received the error "String cannot be of zero length" during the compile.  Maybe this error was corrected in a newer version, we're not quite running the latest and greatest.  I have a workaround so I'm good to go, thank you for your response.

Comment: I'm getting the same error that @user8953898 states.

Comment: I created a pull request that fixes this issue. Hopefully it will get merged. https://github.com/sqlkata/querybuilder/pull/467

Comment: Merged now thanks @GaryBrunton